# Do I remove outliers within training set or duplicate of original?

Tags: outliers, train-test-split

I want to predict on a test set.

I have created a binary logistic regression using my current training set and have predicted on the test set. The dataset I used to split has 299 observations.

What if I want to remove outliers? Do I only remove them within the training set or from the entire dataset and split it once again?

If it's the latter, isn't there a chance that I would end up predicting on the observations that were previously within the training set?

Would I get around this by setting a seed in the programming software `set.seed(123)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We take the data and do our train/test split. We define what an outlier is using our training set *only*. Using this definition we remove outliers from both sets. We continue as normal, i.e. yes, we can remove outliers from our test set, if we think based on our *training* set that they are corrupted data, machine errors, etc.

If use "all" the data together to define our outlier, we have data leakage. Information that we won't have at deployment/testing time normally is used to adjust the training set, which leads to overfitting and poor generalisable performance.

And to state the obvious: An outlier is an outlier irrespective of the seed choice. Changing the random seed does not "fix" any sample quality problems we might have.

Comment: I meant setting the seed to split at the same indexes. This answer clarified everything on my mind. Thank You.

Comment: I am glad I could help. If this answers your question you can consider accepting it as an answer.